# Rails application heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

> Rails 4.1.5 
>   ruby 2.1.2p95 
>   MongoDB - 2.4.13

it works file in local system but when on deplying heroku it gives went wrong

mongodb.yml

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries_on_connection_failure: 20
        persist_in_safe_mode: true
        skip_version_check: true
```

here is heroku log

```
> 2015-12-27T11:48:46.350015+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
2015-12-27T11:48:48.870124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users" host=lit-fjord-5279.herokuapp.com request_id=02419aa9-43c9-4446-b8e9-8a9f7a441b40 fwd="122.172.61.174" dyno=web.1 connect=13ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-12-27T11:48:48.870017+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users" for 122.172.61.174 at 2015-12-27 11:48:48 +0000
2015-12-27T11:48:48.873238+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
2015-12-27T11:48:48.873359+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874438+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874441+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874442+00:00 app[web.1]: message:
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874443+00:00 app[web.1]:   No configuration could be found for a client named 'default'.
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874444+00:00 app[web.1]: summary:
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874445+00:00 app[web.1]:   When attempting to create the new client, Mongoid could not find a client configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874446+00:00 app[web.1]: resolution:
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874446+00:00 app[web.1]:   Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the clients key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.):
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874447+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </thead>
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874450+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:       <tr>
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874450+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:         <td><%= user.name %></td>
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874451+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:         <td><%= user.email %></td>
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874448+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: 
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874448+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <tbody>
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874449+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <% @users.each do |user| %>
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874452+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/index.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__1900358265610175239_69916668256060'
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874453+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-27T11:48:48.874453+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the clients key that a configuration exists for 'default'

File name:

> mongodb.yml

One of these things is not like the other.  Try to rename the file to mongoid.yml

[Mongoid Tutorial, configuration](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#configuration)